# Most graceful way to select a row where multiple fields are NULL in MySQL

Tags: mysql, null

I have a table where most rows are sprinkled with NULLs....but I only want to match those particular rows that hold nothing but NULLs, except for 2 or 3 columns.

Something like

```
SELECT * 
FROM sometable
WHERE
ALL(col1, col2, col3) IS NULL;
```

doesn't work.

Do I really have to write

```
WHERE
co1 IS NULL 
AND
col2 IS NULL
...
AND col150 IS NULL
```

all the way out??

Comment: is the number of columns in where clause dynamic? Please explain your case a bit more

Comment: No it isn't! Just a set of ~100 columns. I loath to have to explicitly express them. Is this my fate, as an SQL user??

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid there's an easier way in doing this.

But you can take help from

> INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS

table.

You can get all the column names of a table by this query.

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'YOUR_DATABASE_NAME'
AND TABLE_NAME = 'YOUR_TABLE_NAME';
```

You can modify this query to make it use in your case.

```
SELECT
    SUBSTRING(
        GROUP_CONCAT(
            (
                CASE
                WHEN COLUMN_NAME NOT IN ('COL1','COLN') THEN
                    CONCAT(
                        COLUMN_NAME,
                        ' IS NULL AND '
                    )
                ELSE
                    ''
                END
            ) SEPARATOR ''
        ),
        1,
        LENGTH(
            GROUP_CONCAT(
                (
                    CASE
                    WHEN COLUMN_NAME NOT IN ('ID') THEN
                        CONCAT(
                            COLUMN_NAME,
                            ' IS NULL AND '
                        )
                    ELSE
                        ''
                    END
                ) SEPARATOR ''
            )
        ) - 4
    )
FROM
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA. COLUMNS
WHERE
    TABLE_SCHEMA = 'YOUR_DATABASE'
AND TABLE_NAME = 'YOUR_TABLE';
```

The above query will generate a string like `'COL2 IS NULL AND COL3 IS NULL'`
Thus you can grab this string and put it in the where condition of your original query.

**N:B:** Mention only those columns ***IN THE WHERE CLAUSE*** [[`CASE WHEN COLUMN_NAME NOT IN ('COL1','COLN')`]] which are not supposed to check NULLABILITY.

Comment: Wow! This is cool. I'm going to try it at work tomorrow. Thanks.

Comment: You are welcome. Please let me know if it works for you. :)